# Determinant of a Matrix 2

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $A$ be an $(n-1)\times(n-1)$ matrix such that $\det(A)\ne0$, let $B$ be an $(n-1)\times 1$ matrix and let $C$ be a $1\times(n-1)$ matrix. Show that there exists a real number $t$ such that $$\det\begin{bmatrix}
>     A       & B    \\
>     C       & t
> \end{bmatrix} = 0.$$

This is a practice exam question and I have no idea how to solve it? I know that $t$ must be a $1\times 1$ hence the column of $B$ and $t$ is size one, but other than that I am stumped.

Comment: Note that since $\operatorname{det}(A) \neq 0$, $C$ is a linear combination of the rows of $A$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\;A\;$ is invertible $\;\implies\;$ $\;B\in\text{Span}\,\{\text{columns of}\;A\}\;$ , say

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}a_i\gamma_i=B\;,\;\;\gamma_i=\text{the columns of}\;\;A\;,\;\;a_i\;\;\text{scalars}$$

Well, now just **take**

$$t=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}a_ic_i\;,\;\;C=(c_1,\,c_2,\,\ldots,\,c_{n-1})$$

Comment: Why does $A$ being invertible imply that $\;B\in\text{Span}\,\{\text{columns of}\;A\}\;$? Also, what is $c_i$?

Comment: $\;A\;$ is invertible iff $\;Ax=b\;$ has a *unique* solution for each $\;b\;$ . This follows from the general theory oflinear equations of, even simpler, from, the dimensions theorem for linear operators/matrices on finitedimensional spaces. The $\;c_i$'s are, *as defined in the answer*, the coordinates of the vector (or $\;1\times (n-1)\;$ matrix) $\;C\;$

Answer (score 1):

Since $\det(A) \not = 0$, rows of $A$ are basis for $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$. Therefore, $C$ can be written as:

$$
C = \lambda_1 a_1 + \dots + \lambda_{n-1} a_{n-1}
$$
where $a_1, \dots , a_{n-1}$ are rows of $A$. Now for the whole matrix if you add $-\lambda_1[a_1 \quad b_1]$, $-\lambda_2[a_2 \quad b_2]$, $\dots$ to the last row, you will get all zeros in columns $1, \dots, n-1$ and the following value in last column:

$$
t-\lambda_1b_1 - \dots - \lambda_{n-1}b_{n-1}
$$
that can be zero by setting:
$$
t=\lambda_1b_1 + \dots + \lambda_{n-1}b_{n-1}
$$

Answer (score 1):

You want to solve
$$\det\begin{bmatrix}
    A       & B    \\
    C       & t
\end{bmatrix} = 0.$$
Using Laplace expansion (see [Laplace expansion on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion)), you get:
$$ \det(A) t + \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} (-1)^{n+i} b_i \times \det( \text{Some matrix}) = 0 .$$
Since you know that $\det(A) \neq 0$, there is a unique solution to this affine equation:
$$ t = - \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} (-1)^{n+i} b_i \times \det( \text{Some matrix})}{\det(A) }$$